# Clion+PlatformIO arduino avr-gcc unrecognized command line option

Tags: arduino, clion, mingw-w64, platformio

Clean installed Clion 2020.1 + Platformio 6.1.9 (using py script from official page) + Platformio clion plugin.
Tried to set multiple versions of MinGW toolchains but none is working, after "Re Init" Cmake shows this message:

```
Problems were encountered while collecting compiler information:
avr-gcc.exe: error: unrecognized command line option '-std=gnu11;-fno-fat-lto-objects;-mmcu=atmega328p;-Os;-Wall;-ffunction-sections;-fdata-sections;-flto'
```

Latest mingw used: i686-8.1.0-release-posix-dwarf-rt_v6-rev0.
Also tried to set gcc and g++ compilers from avr8-gnu-toolchain, didn't help.
And there is no mention about a toolchain on Platformio documentation.

I'll be happy for any tutorial or help
[image]

Answer (score 0):

`-std=gnu11;-fno-fat-lto-objects;-mmcu=atmega328p;-Os;-Wall;-ffunction-sections;-fdata-sections;-flto` is not a valid gcc option. Remove these `;`'s.